# How to handle overlapped signals in cantools library

Tags: python, can-bus

Have a canbus database record of multiplexed message with two overlapped signals (at position 8 and 32) like this:

```
[A0AT]
Len=8
CycleTime=1000
Mux=_10 0,8 0Ah
Var=Signal00 unsigned 8,7 /u:°C /o:-40 /max:80 /e:Signal00
Var=Signal01 bit 15,1 /e:Signal01
Var=Signal02 unsigned 16,2
Var=Signal03 unsigned 18,2
Var=Signal04 unsigned 28,4 /e:Signal04
Var=Signal05 unsigned 24,2 /e:Signal05
Var=Signal06 unsigned 32,7 /u:°C /o:-40 /e:Signal06
Var=Signal07 unsigned 56,8 /u:°C /e:Signal07
Var=Signal08 unsigned 40,8 /u:°C /o:-40 /e:Signal08
Var=Signal09 unsigned 48,8 /u:°C /o:-40 /e:Signal09
Var=Signal10 unsigned 26,2 /e:Signal10
Var=Signal11 bit 39,1
Var=Signal12 unsigned 8,7 /u:°F /o:32
Var=Signal13 unsigned 32,7 /u:°F /o:32 /e:Signal13
Var=Signal14 unsigned 20,4 /e:Signal14
```

But my message from device is:

`0.124000 1   1BBBBBB0x      Rx  d 8 0A 3E F0 FF FF FF FF 00`

Simple decoding by cantools library

```
dced_msg = db.decode_message(mesg.arbitration_id, mesg.data)
```

fails because of missing data in message.

Is there a way to use the cantools library and correctly decode such message (i.e fill these duplicated signals with correct values)?

Or is there any other can bus communication library which can handle overlapped signals?

Comment: What kind of message description is that? Signal 12 and 13 should probably be read for another Mux value... 0Ah for °C and xxh for °F...

Comment: It is sym database record. I have approx 200GB of messages and related database has hundreds multiplexed records with overlapped signals. I believe the message is not possible (easily) convert for another mux. The output should just fill Signals 12 and 13 with different values  than 00 and 06. The cantools library is not capable to handle such double use of same inputs - by my understanding.  Commercial PCAN software can do it so maybe some of PCAN libraries can be used instead of cantools.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has already been raised on the `cantools` repo: https://github.com/cantools/cantools/issues/205

Unfortunately the library doesn't support overlapping signals at the moment and probably never will.

You could try to convert your .sym files to .dbc using [canmatrix](https://github.com/ebroecker/canmatrix) and decode your can signals with [can_decoder](https://github.com/CSS-Electronics/can_decoder). I haven't tested it though.